# Como converter um diretório inteiro de vídeos via terminal no Ubuntu Server 18?

Tags: shell

Eu tenho um diretório e queria converter todos os vídeos .mkv para .mp4.

O único problema que estou tendo é:

```
ffmpeg -f concact-i lista.txt -c copy novo.mp4
```

o único problema é que dessa forma eu pego todo o diretório mas sai em um único vídeo.
 Eu gostaria de pegar todos e converter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É muito simples usando o `ffmpeg`.
Para converter apenas um arquivo você utiliza o:

```
ffmpeg -i arquivo.mkv -codec copy arquivo.mp4
```

Aqui, você está copiando o codec de vídeo e o codec de áudio para que nada seja codificado e a qualidade reduzida.

Para converter todos os arquivos MKV no diretório atual, execute um loop simples no terminal:

```
r i in *.mkv; 
do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec copy "${i%.*}.mp4"
done
```

Observação: Aparentemente legendas inclusas no MKV não são convertidas junto com o MKV.

Uma dica, tente criar um alias no Ubuntu com esse loop, assim quando quiser converter todos os MKV de uma pasta para MP4, basta entrar na pasta e executar o alias.

Comment: Olha... Muito obrigado viu! Vou fazer isso nas próximas vezes.
Acabei que tendo de fazer um script manual pra fazer ele rodar automático. Imagina o trabalho.